# Setting the ipads detailViewController to a UIWebView

Tags: ipad, ios

How does one Set the Ipads detailViewController to a UIWebView so that it still works as a spiltview?

How can the Detail Item be changed to display a UIWebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the existing detailViewController *(assuming you are going off of a tutorial)* and add a full screen `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about the detail view from a split view, you could build the split view manually, and make the detail view a UIWebView.

Apple has great documentation (and an example) for building a SplitView manually.

You can find it here: [View Controller Programming Guide for IOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

It's really not hard to do - Apple's instructions are a great place to start.